# Is there an effect on condensation when the elevation is changed?

Tags: humidity, condensation

So, I'm working on a test for a project and we want to see if any condensation occurs.

The relative humidity temperature are fixed.  From this we can find the dew point, which will give us a good idea of whether or not we will see condensation.

My question is, if I run this test at sea level and then again at a higher elevation, such as Denver, will I see a change in my results?

Since relative humidity is the vapor pressure/saturation vapor pressure I'm thinking it might have to do with this.  Correct me if I am wrong but the vapor pressure will not be affected by the altitude, however, the saturation level of vapor pressure will be lower.  Would I have less available water to condense at the dew point?  So I would still have condensation at the same temperature but maybe my total volume of condensation would be less?  Would the differences be negligible? i.e. 1 ml of change?

Comment: Water vapor pressure is only a function of temperature, not ambient pressure.  Please provide details of what test you are running.  The details may well strongly affect the answer that you get.

Comment: I’m running different fixed temperature and fixed relative humidity conditions and then seeing how much condensate occurs at these different combinations.  So if I were to rerun these same fixed temperature and fixed relative humidity combinations  at an elevation higher then sea level, would I see any difference in the condensation at all?